# Failed to fetch component listing from server. C heck your network settings and try again

Tags: google-app-engine

Am getting below error from Win8 machine.

D:\EO\downloads1\google-cloud-sdk-168.0.0-windows-x86-bundled-python\google-clou
d-sdk>install.bat
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics. You may choose
to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below prompt), or at
any time in the future by running the following command:

```
gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true
```

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?  y

to_install
ERROR: (gcloud.components.list) Failed to fetch component listing from server. C
heck your network settings and try again.

Thanks,
Sekhar

Comment: Same problem here ! do you fin any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was due to our enterprise proxy performing TLS inspection and resigning with a custom cert. This cert is trusted by our managed devices browsers. However gcloud uses it's own truststore. You can add additional certs by storing them in PEM format and configuring gcloud as follows:

```
gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file C:\path\to\cert-pem\proxy-certs.pem
```